# Can't get html element using js file in SPFX

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I am trying to build dynamic content from a SharePoint list using SPFX.  I'd like to use jQuery to build an accordion view of the data.  The issue is that I can't even seem to get the element once the page is rendered.

In my code I am requiring a file called ota.js with the following code:

```
console.log('Start');

function otaExpand(){
    console.log('otaExpand Function Called');     
    let spListContainer = document.getElementById('spListContainer');
    console.log(spListContainer);
}
window.addEventListener("load", otaExpand());
```

In my ts file this is my render method:

```
public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <div id="spListContainer">TEST</div>
      </div>
    `;
      //this._renderListAsync();
      //($('.accordion', this.domElement) as any).accordion();
  }
```

When I review the console, I get my messages, but the element itself comes back as null.
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFUUx.png)

I am using SharePoint 2019 on premise with the following configuration.

+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0

+-- gulp-cli@2.3.0

`-- yo@2.0.6

node --version

v8.17.0

I should also mention I am using TypeScript with no JavaScript framework.

Does anyone know why I can't access this element from my js file?

Thanks!

My overall goal is to call list data and apply an accordion style to it (https://jqueryui.com/accordion), but I can't even get passed capturing the element to change it.

I've tried calling my code from a js file as well as trying to put the code directly in the html.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally figured out what I was doing wrong.  I was calling my jQuery in the render() method rather than in _renderList where this.domElement actually makes sense.

Here's my code in case anyone wants to avoid the pain I put myself through.  This allows you to specify a list in the site and you just need to add the fields you want to display.

```
    import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
    BaseClientSideWebPart,
    IPropertyPaneChoiceGroupOption,
    IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
    PropertyPaneChoiceGroup,
    PropertyPaneCustomField,
    PropertyPaneTextField
  } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
  import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
  
  import styles from './GetSpListItemsWebPart.module.scss';
  import * as strings from 'GetSpListItemsWebPartStrings';
  
  import {
    SPHttpClient,
    SPHttpClientResponse   
  } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
  
  import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
  import 'jqueryui';
  import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
  import PropertyPane from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base/lib/propertyPane/propertyPane/PropertyPane';
  
  export interface IGetSpListItemsWebPartProps {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    listField: string;
  }
  export interface ISPLists {
    value: ISPList[];
  }
  
  export interface ISPList {
    ID: string;
    Title: string;
    Website: {
      Description : string,
      Url : string
    };
    Description : string;
  }
    
  export default class GetSpListItemsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IGetSpListItemsWebPartProps> {
    private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
      return this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + this.properties.listField + "')/Items",SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
          .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
            return response.json();
          });
    }
  
    private _renderListAsync(): void {
      this._getListData()
        .then((response) => {
          this._renderList(response.value);
        })
        .catch(() => {});
    }
  
    private _renderList(items: ISPList[]): void {
      let listData = `
      <h1>${this.properties.title}</h1>
      <h2>${this.properties.description}</h2>
      <div class="accordion">
      `;
      items.forEach((item: ISPList) => {      
        let Description : string;
        item.Description ? Description = item.Description : Description = "";
        
        listData += `          
          <h3>&nbsp;${item.Title}</h3>
          <div>
              <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>OTA URL</td>
                    <td><a href="${item.Website.Url}" target="_blank">${item.Website.Description}</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Description</td>
                  <td>${Description}</td>
                </tr>            
              </table>
          </div>
          `;
      });
      listData += '</div>';
  
      this.domElement.innerHTML = listData;   
      const accordionOptions: JQueryUI.AccordionOptions = {
        animate: true,
        collapsible: true,
        icons: {
          header: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e',
          activeHeader: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s'
        }
      };
        jQuery('.accordion', this.domElement).accordion(accordionOptions);
      
    }
  
    public render(): void {
      this._renderListAsync();      
    }
  
    protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
      return {
        pages: [
          {
            header: {
              description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
            },
            groups: [
              {
                groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
                groupFields: [
                  PropertyPaneTextField('title',{
                    label: strings.TitleFieldLabel
                  }),
                  PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                    label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                  }),
                  PropertyPaneTextField('listField', {
                    label: strings.ListFieldLabel
                  })
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  
    public constructor() {
      super();
    
     SPComponentLoader.loadCss('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
      
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code from the "ota.js" file is probably called before your HTML is initialized (i.e. before the "render()" function is executed). To make sure this is the case, you could add log to the "render()" function to see when it's called.

In other words, "window.load" event happens long before "render()" function is called. This is how web parts are loaded - dynamically after full load of the page. Or "window.load" does not happen at all - web parts may be loaded by the user when using the page designer, i.e. without page reload.

To fix the issue, you should get the element after it's created, i.e. after the "render()" function creates the element you are trying to get.

Comment: So I did get a little further with this after I posted the issue.  It seems like I wasn't referencing the elements correctly.  This article gave me some information, and I can reference the information in the webpart now. https://n8d.at/this-domelement-is-your-new-document-object-in-spfx-web-parts-development.  this.domElement doesn't seem to work in my external js file though.  I can only access the information by using document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('classname').  I guess I need to understand how to properly call elements in the webparts.

Comment: if you want to use this.domElement somewhere outside of the web part, you need to pass it there. "this." inside of a class or function refers to the current class or function

Comment: I still need to manipulate the data within the web part.  My end goal is to dynamically call list data and then run my JavaScript function on the results.  Does anyone have a good online example of how this can be done?

Comment: You can head over to the official web part samples site - there are more than 1000 sample web parts available, with source code: https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-webparts

Comment: Thanks Nikolay.  I will definitely check this out!